# Free product stock management software

Tags: open-source, photography, asset-management, product-management, clothing

I'm searching for an app/software to handle stock (in this case, second-hand clothes). I'm a web developer myself and so I thought of developing something by my own, but as usual, this is something that should be done already, adding to the lack of time and the fact that I'm don't have that much experience. Still regarding this, I've already developed a MariaDB database, but development stopped there. Currently it is being used a Google Spreadsheet with some enhancements (e.g. allowing to select the colours / materials / sellers from a predefined - and editable - list). The stock is now >1000 articles and so this solution is increasingly turning into something unpractical & slow. I've searched for some solutions (namely on AlternativeTo) but with little conclusions. The main features I'm looking for are:

**Mandatory:**

- Photo on each product detail page
- Calculate the total amount due to each provider (i.e. people who deliver clothes to be sell on consignment at the store)
- Free

**Nice to have:**

- Open-source
- Preferably an web/cloud app over a desktop app (although offline editing is also a nice to have, sometimes wi-fi may not be available)
- As mentioned above, there are already more than 1000 products into the Google Spreadsheet, so a great nice to have feature is the ability to import products as a CSV/TSV file (I think the most suitable formats that Google Sheets can export to are these)

**Note:** if there is something out there low-code that is suitable for these needs, of course that can also be an option!

Still regarding my searches some months ago on AlternativeTo, I've looked into Snipe-IT but it seems that either I have to host it myself or pay for the hosted service. I also considered using forms (LibreOffice Base), but as I've tried it, it seems to be clumsy and with several bugs. Looking into my AlternativeTo list, I was also considering messing around with Zoho Creator and nuBuilder Forte, but still haven't. Should any of these be a good option? What other options would you recommend? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Depeding on how to do this, you could even use an open source ecommerce system to do this e.g. opencart, drupal commerce, etc. I can enter full asnwer if of interest. There are also some Android apps that can handle inventory.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, and yes if you could elaborate on that I would be grateful!

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comment above you could try one of the web ecommerce systems like:

- [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) - I have used this in the past. It has ability to display products, inventory, photos etc. it also has an importer module to load products, you can create reports, etc. But you will have to learn to use drupal. It is web-based open source, but can run on a mobile phone. You an create mobile app if you want but that is separate work...
- The alternative is another system [Opencart](https://www.opencart.com). Also open source.

For an Android app, I have used [Tabshop](https://tabshop.smartlab.at/) in the past for Inventory Management. There is a free version. The Pro version cost about 5EUR when I used it.

Comment: Thanks for your (useful) reply. I've messed around a little bit with OpenCart 5 years ago, I'll take another look into it. I believe that the most tricky requirement here is the ability to calculate the total amount due to each provider, but I'll try to find if there is anything out there that satisfies this.

Comment: In the past when I used drupal, it would have been quite straighforward to construct a report using Views module e.g. product, supplier, price, quantity, price*quantity. I can't recall how in Opencart as I did not use it extensively.